# how to append the following data in a xml tag to get xml file as output?

Tags: jquery

```
{
    "attrs": {
        "width": 578,
        "height": 200
    },
    "nodeType": "Stage",
    "children": [
        {
            "attrs": {},
            "nodeType": "Layer",
            "children": [
                {
                    "attrs": {
                        "x": 289,
                        "y": 100,
                        "sides": 6,
                        "radius": 70,
                        "fill": "red",
                        "stroke": "black",
                        "strokeWidth": 4
                    },
                    "nodeType": "Shape",
                    "shapeType": "RegularPolygon"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have parsed the above json data but i dont know how to append the data to xml tag.thanks for any help.I want the xml tags with exact parent and child nodes using jquery.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So you just want to convert from json to xml? [tons of scripts on the net](http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/)

jsFiddle using the obove lib: http://jsfiddle.net/RCZLF/

```
var foo = {/* json obj */}
$(function() {
    console.log(json2xml(foo,' '));
});
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I found this function after a quick Google search ([source](http://onwebdevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/05/converting-xml-to-json.html)):

```
json2Xml = function(json, node) {
    var root = false;
    if (!node) {
        node = document.createElement('root');
        root = true;
    }

    for (var x in json) {
        // ignore inherited properties
        if (json.hasOwnProperty(x)) {

            if (x == '#text') { // text
                node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(json[x]));
            } else  if (x == '@attributes') { // attributes
                for (var y in json[x]) {
                    if (json[x].hasOwnProperty(y)) {
                        node.setAttribute(y, json[x][y]);
                    }
                }
            } else if (x == '#comment') { // comment
                // ignore
            } else { // elements
                if (json[x] instanceof Array) { // handle arrays
                    for (var i = 0; i < json[x].length; i++) {
                        node.appendChild(json2Xml(json[x][i], document.createElement(x)));
                    }
                } else {
                    node.appendChild(json2Xml(json[x], document.createElement(x)));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (root == true) {
        return this.textToXML(node.innerHTML);
    } else {
        return node;
    }
};
```